# Fatal Errors after moving site

Tags: error

A client has moved a magento installation to a new server, I believe they have just copied the lot over - files and database.

The site is now kinda functional but there is lots of stuff missing. Product categories are there but no products are displayed and no errors are showing. On the home page under special offers the following error showed:

> Fatal error: Class
>   '*Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract*' not found in
>   */path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Groupprice.php*
>   on line 36

in Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Groupprice there is a file called Abs (just Abs, no extension) which looks like a regular php file and which declares the following class:

```
abstract class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
```

So I saved it to the same location as Abstract.php and it cleared up the above error. 
Now in the admin area when I go to Catalog->Manage Products the following error shows:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function createFromConfiguration() on a
>   non-object in
>
> /path/to/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Item.php
>   on line 92

Does this look like a familiar story? Is it likely something has gone wrong while the files were copied? Do I need to see if the old site is still there and copy it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some files are missing or were not copied correctly. Try to copy them again and overwrite everything you have in your new hosting.

FTP is the often used option but it does not provide security or consistncy, try using rsync or SCP if you have SSH access.

Comment: Thanks @mbalparda :-) we will just have to do it again I guess